# More problems in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I recently found the following problem. I want to practice more in such problems. Please refer me to some sources or problems like these involving miscellaneous problems on differential equations.

If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions of the differential equation $dy/dx+ P(x) \cdot y = Q (x)$ then prove that $y = + c(y_1- y_2) dx$ is the general solution of the equation, where $c$ is any constant.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: you may find it useful to know a few things about the site. To get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. 

Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I would recommend investing in a diffeq textbook and using the exercises to practice.  The Edwards/Penney book is a popular staple.